# Create N linked lists being N a number from keyboard in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a problem with my program. I'll try to explain so that you can help me.

Imagine you want to have `N` bags, and for each of them, you want to input a number of balls (with max number of balls = 10 for each bag).

I have a function that first introduces the number `N` of bags, then it reads a line of input from the user for each of these bags, like `1 3 4 9`, indicating the elements that are input into that bag, and so on for each bag until the bag `N`.

The problem I have is, how can I "remember" the order in which the balls were input after introducing them all?  In the example line above, the order would be 1 first, then 3, then 4, and finally 9.

In other functions I need that for each bag `i`, get its elements in the order that they were input, and do some things with them.

My code is something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < N ; i ++){
    //read all numbers
    //and for each number "j"
    G[i][j] = true;
}
```

Where `G` is `bool G[x][y]`, which I use to create a relation between elements with its bag, but this doesn't work since it doesn't gives me the order of the input.

I thought about creating a Linked List, but I don't know how to create `N` lists with `N` given from keyboard, and after that access each list.

I don't know if it is clear, but I don't need random access to each element of each bag, I just need that for one bag, iterate over its elements in the order they were input.

Comment: Linked lists are not normally accessed using the `[]` operator.

Comment: I know but I dont need random access to each element of bag, I just need to access to its elements in the order they were input

Comment: The values are stored in whatever order you store them in.  Read a number, put it in a list.  Read the next number, put it in the next slot of the same list.  And on on. Then you iterate the list from first to last.  The values will be in the same order they were input.  What exactly are you having trouble with about this?

Comment: @Uwunt *but I don't know how to create N lists* -- `std::vector<MyLinkedListClass> Lists(N);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the type of situation that `std::vector` is good for.  You don't need to use linked lists (like `std::list`).

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>

struct Bag
{
    int NumBalls;
    int Balls[10];

    Bag() : NumBalls(0) {}
};

int main()
{
    int N;
    std::cout << "How many bags do you want? ";

    if (!((std::cin >> N) && (N > 0)))
    {
        std::cout << "Bad input!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    std::vector<Bag> Bags(N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter balls for bag " << i+1 << ": ";

        std::string line;
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, line))
            break;

        std::istringstream iss(line);

        Bag &bag = Bags[i];
        int ball;

        do
        {
            if (!(iss >> ball))
            {
                if (!iss.eof())
                    std::cout << "Bad input!" << std::endl;
                break;
            }

            bag.Balls[bag.NumBalls] = ball;
            bag.NumBalls++;
        }
        while (bag.NumBalls < 10);
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Bag " << i+1 << " contains:";

        Bag &bag = Bags[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < bag.NumBalls; ++j)
            std::cout << " " << bag.Balls[j];

        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/cuC1sE)